# ColdFusion Rest Component

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

How can I call a rest component in ColdFusion? I create the file test.cfc.

```
component displayName="Test" rest="true" restPath="Test" {
   public any function method1(data) access="remote" httpmethod="GET" returnformat="JSON" {
      ...
   }
}
```

This file is located: root/myApp/components/test.cfc

I tried to open by: https://mytestsite.com/myApp/components/Test 
However, it returns error 404 - Not Found

Comment: well, it's called test.cfc, so... start there maybe?

Comment: It should be REST

Comment: Not according to the code posted above...

Comment: That's why I asked the question. I'm new with ColdFusion, if I knew the solution, I wouldn't ask. What in the code shows that it is not a REST?

Comment: You dont call the entire component, you call the specific function of a component,  `https://mytestsite.com/path/to/test.cfc?method=method1&data=somedata`

Comment: Try accessing it with `https://mytestsite.com/myApp/components/Test.cfc?method=method1`  first. Notice it doesn't compile? Because it has too many "access" attributes (public and remote)

Comment: Why do I need to enter the method name? Shouldn't it be just /Test/Test? Like a REST API

Comment: To verify the code actually works before going any further ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Please find the YouTube link to a tutorial using CF Rest and Angular.

https://youtu.be/4GkXanOqH88

Below is link to sample code on CF Rest

https://github.com/mayuranchalia/DeveloperWeek

localhost:8500/rest/(restmapping)/Test

Rest mapping you provide when registering the service in ColdFusion Administrator.

https://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html

Comment: You should include some sample code and screen shots. Link only answers like this  are usually removed.

Comment: Code sample example?

Comment: Based on the question, i felt sample code would not suffice so shared the above links. You are making an RPC call when you call a cfc with method as query parameter. Just by adding component function doesn't enable the service to be accessible restfully, you need to register the cfc in CF admin. And there are various ways of calling rest service using HTTP Verb. Please also read about rest architecture style. For code sample I have shared the GitHub link, please follow it. Have also shared the Adobe devnet link which talks in details how you can create rest services in ColdFusion.